# C++11 when increment the atomic variable, and assign it to other value, is it atomic operation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, atomic

i'm confused about the atomic operation on c++11,

i know the atomic variable self increment is atomic operation,

but i use the assignment to other value, just doubt it.

the code just like:

```
//....
static std::atomic<int> i; // global variable
//....
// in the thread
int id = ++i;
```

when using the assignment at different threads, is the id unique value?

the test code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    static int idGenerator;
    static std::mutex m;
    A () {
        // i know this operation will keep the id_ is unique
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        id_ = ++idGenerator; 
    }
   void F(std::string name) {
         std::cout << name << " " << id_ << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int id_;
};
int A::idGenerator = 0;
std::mutex A::m;

class B {
public:
    static int idGenerator;
    B () {
        // after self increment, is the assignment atomic? 
        id_ = (++idGenerator);
    }
   void F(std::string name) {
         std::cout << name << " " << id_.load() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::atomic<int> id_;
};
int B::idGenerator = 0;


void funcA() {
    A a2;
    a2.F("a2");
}

void funcB() {
    B b2;
    b2.F("b2");
}

int main() {
    A a1;
    B b1;
    std::thread t1(&funcA);
    std::thread t2(&funcB);
    a1.F("a1");
    b1.F("b1");

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

there are three threads,

A class use lock_guard keep unique.

B class just use atomic operation, and assign to the variable

Comment: See the API `std::atomic::fetch_add` that covers the two operations in an atomic unit.

Comment: An assignment to an atomic variable (or an increment operation) is, well, atomic. An assignment to any other variable is not guaranteed to be atomic. However, atomicity alone is not sufficient in all scenarios with concurrent access in order to make it "thread-safe". Furthermore, looking at your code in class `B`, it seems you want to make the static member variable `idGenerator` atomic, instead member variable `id_`.

Comment: i'm read the crtmpserver code, and each connection with its only one iohandler class, the iohandler's id is generated by the static generateId. crtmpserver is Single Process, if i try to add multithread support,   the id should keep unique as before

Answer (score 13):

The specification of the atomic increment functions give a crucial insight into their behaviour - from    http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith for Integral `T` types:

```
T operator++();
T operator++() volatile;
T operator++( int );
T operator++( int ) volatile;
```

Notice they return a `T` by value, and never return the usual `T&` from a pre-increment.  For that reason, the "read" of post-incremented value is not a second distinct operation, and is part of the atomic increment operation itself.

See also the "Return Value" and "Note" text on the above-linked page.

Comment: thanks!!!, i using the visual studio 2013 to debug the code, it call atomic_fetch_add to keep atomic.

Answer (score 6):

```
static std::atomic<int> i; // global variable
// in the thread
int id = ++i;
```

> when using the assignment at different threads, is the id unique value?

Yes.
C++ atomic variables ensure that `++i` will be evaluated atomically, so each values of `id` on different threads are unique.

The expression `id = ++i;` is executed following steps.

1. atomically increment `i`, and sub-expression(`++i`) is evaluated post-increment value.
2. assign "evaluated value" to `id`. (this step is non-atomically)

Answer (score 0):

kaka_ace,

Unfortunately in the case you provided, it isn't atomic.

Here's the reason why the pre-increment operation is atomic, look at the assembly generated:

```
 add %l0,1,%l0
```

(might vary a little bit depending on the assembly used)

But that's it. 1 operation. That's why it's atomic.

When you're assigning a pre-increment to a local variable, that's at least two instructions:

```
add %l0,1,%l0
st l0, [%fp-4]
```

That generates at least two instructions, and hence is no longer atomic.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Your `add %l0,1,%l0` shows the code's using a CPU register to store the atomic value - that's not going to be modified from other threads anyway, so is effectively atomic.  The interesting/meaningful case is where the atomic variable may be modified by another thread - then it's the code modifying the atomic value *in memory* that's relevant - whether the C++ Standard requires an opcode that manages to both increment the memory address atomically and avoid a second read to get the value for `id` in the question's code.

Comment: @TonyD, ahh I see; thank you for the clarification and your answer as well! Enjoyed learning something new and seeing and understanding the importance and context of the atomicity in reads in shared memory between threads.

Comment: no worries - was nice to see some Sparc assembly!  Actually - my comment above talked about requiring an opcode, but that's misleading as on CPUs that don't have such support the atomic operations may fall back on a mutex and have many machine opcodes involved.  Cheers.